# Use of \noexpand in the implementation of \TextOrMath for eTeX

Tags: macros, expansion, definition, protected-macro

In `latexrelease` 2015/01/01, there are two implementations of `\TextOrMath`: one for regular 
TeX, the other one for eTeX-like engines (more precisely: those which support `\protected`). My question concerns the latter:

```
\protected\expandafter\def\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname{%
  (...) } % no problem here
\edef\TextOrMath#1#2{% from latex.ltx
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname
  {#1}{#2}}
```

I think I understand well these definitions, however I can't figure out why the `\edef` isn't simply written this way:

```
\edef\TextOrMath#1#2{% from me
  \csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname
  {#1}{#2}}
```

Since the internal `\TextOrMath<space>` macro is `\protected`, what is the point of preceding it with `\noexpand` inside the `\edef`? Is it because the author feared that `\protected` might be deficient?..

I made a test like this (ran with pdfTeX):

```
% From latex.ltx (or p. 153 of source2e.pdf)
\protected\expandafter\def\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname{%
  \ifmmode  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else     \expandafter\@firstoftwo  \fi}

\edef\TextOrMath#1#2{%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname
  {#1}{#2}}

% My simpler way of doing the same (?)
\edef\altTextOrMath#1#2{%
  \csname TextOrMath\space\endcsname
  {#1}{#2}}

\show\TextOrMath    % \TextOrMath=macro:#1#2->\TextOrMath  {#1}{#2}.
\show\altTextOrMath % \altTextOrMath=ditto

\ifx\TextOrMath\altTextOrMath
  identical
\else
  different
\fi

\vfill
\eject
\bye
```

This test prints 'identical' and seems to indicate that my definition is equivalent to the one in latex.ltx (but slightly simpler). Did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks I suppose we could change that:-)

Comment: Many thanks for your insight into this, I was really puzzled!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you didn't miss anything, just old habits die hard as we gradually add these modern post 1992 features into the sources....